# React useState doesn't update

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mqtt

I'm trying to make a small webpage for a project. I use an esp32 to send a payload with MQTT. I want to show this message on a react app. but my postboxStatus doesn't update with the useState block. Quite new to react so hope this isn't a dumb question.

```
import { useState } from 'react'

function Main() {

    const [postboxStatus, setPostboxStatus] = useState("empty");

    const mqtt = require('mqtt')

    const host = 'test.mosquitto.org'
    const port = '1883'
    const clientId = `mqtt_${Math.random().toString(16).slice(3)}`
    
    const connectUrl = `mqtt://${host}:${port}`
    const client = mqtt.connect(connectUrl, {
      clientId,
      clean: true,
      connectTimeout: 4000,
      username: '14501288',
      password: '',
      reconnectPeriod: 1000,
    })
    
    const topic = 'postbox/sta'
    
    client.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('Connected')
      client.subscribe([topic], () => {
        console.log(`Subscribe to topic '${topic}'`)
      })
      client.publish(topic, 'nodejs mqtt test', { qos: 0, retain: false }, (error) => {
        if (error) {
          console.error(error)
        }
      })
    })
    client.on('message', (topic, payload) => {
      console.log('Received Message:', topic, payload.toString())
      setPostboxStatus(payload.toString())
    })
    

  return (
    <div>
        <h1> {postboxStatus} </h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Main;
```

Comment: So is the message received? Also never connect or bind to an event listener every render!.. move that into a `useEffect(() => { ... }, [])`

Comment: Yes I receive the messages from the topic @Dominic

Comment: Also move `require('mqtt')` to a normal import. Connecting to `mqtt` protocol in the browser will not work, that will only work on a NodeJS server, you would have to use `ws` or `wss` in the browser so I'm not sure how that callback could be working for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving a message in the `onMessage` listener and updating the `postboxStatus` state, use an `useEffect` hook to add and remove the listeners. You ought not create a new `client` every render cycle either.

Example:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const mqtt = require('mqtt');

const host = 'test.mosquitto.org';
const port = '1883';
const connectUrl = `mqtt://${host}:${port}`;

const topic = 'postbox/sta';

function Main() {
  const [postboxStatus, setPostboxStatus] = useState("empty");

  useEffect(() => {
    const clientId = `mqtt_${Math.random().toString(16).slice(3)}`;

    const client = mqtt.connect(connectUrl, {
      clientId,
      clean: true,
      connectTimeout: 4000,
      username: '14501288',
      password: '',
      reconnectPeriod: 1000,
    });

    client.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('Connected');
      client.subscribe([topic], () => {
        console.log(`Subscribe to topic '${topic}'`)
      });

      client.publish(topic, 'nodejs mqtt test', { qos: 0, retain: false }, (error) => {
        if (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      });
    });

    client.on('message', (topic, payload) => {
      console.log('Received Message:', topic, payload.toString());
      setPostboxStatus(payload.toString());
    });

    return () => client.end();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{postboxStatus}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Main;
```